LVM on cloud init ubuntu 22.04 server
I'm using packer from hashicorp, to install ubuntu 22.04 server on vmware. There is a one problem, i can't find how to specify volume group and logical volume in user-data file.
For example i need that in sda or sdb will be volume group main, and in it logical volume root
For now storage section in user-data looks like this:
storage:
layout:
name: lvm
sizing-policy: all
I trying to search in official page of ubuntu, to cloud-init, but i don't understand it
